# Format tab in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to format text in a RichTextBox like the folowing example:

"A tab-space here" TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT.

"A tab-space here" TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT.

"A tab-space here" TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT.

If I format the text in word and paste it into the RichTextBox control visually I can see "styled" in the format I am looking for. Once I submit the text and debug the RichTextBox content, the tab-space at the beginning of each line disappears.

*Side Note: I am very interested in achieving this since I use this control to paste in it python scripts.*

How can I avoid that ?

**EDIT:**

I have the following code:

```
var html = string.Empty;
var wholeText = new TextRange(block.ContentStart, block.ContentEnd);
html += wholeText.Text;
```

In debug mode I take a look at wholeText.Text to see how the text is formatted (I can see it as a text/html or xml editor). At this point is where I don't see the tab-spaces that I've described before.

Comment: so you're saying that when you first paste it into the Rich Text Box, you can see that it has the tab (correctly) - but when you click submit it loses that tab/white-space at the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem by using this:

```
 countOfSpaces = text.TakeWhile(c => c.Equals('\t')).Count();
 replacedrunText = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("<pre>&#9;", countOfSpaces)) +
                                  text.Substring(countOfSpaces);
 replacedrunText += "</pre>";
```